# Evaluating integral of a summation

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

For $0<a<b$,

$\int_0^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty ( ae^{-anx} -be^{-bnx} ) dx  $ and the answer is supposed to be $\log(b/a)$ .

I am having major troubles with this. The summation inside seems to be $ \frac{a}{e^{ax} -1} - \frac{b}{e^{bx} -1} $ by geometric. The integral of which is :
$\left[\ln\left( \frac{1-e^{ax}}{1-e^{bx}} \right) +(b-a)x )\right]^\infty_0$ which does not give the right answer. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(ae^{-anx}-be^{-bnx}\right)=\frac{ae^{-ax}}{1-e^{-ax}}-\frac{be^{-bx}}{1-e^{-bx}}$$

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{ae^{-ax}}{1-e^{-ax}}-\frac{be^{-bx}}{1-e^{-bx}}\right)\,dx&=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\lim_{L\to \infty}\int_{\epsilon}^{L}\left(\frac{ae^{-ax}}{1-e^{-ax}}-\frac{be^{-bx}}{1-e^{-bx}}\right)\,dx\\\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\lim_{L\to \infty}\left.\log\left(\frac{1-e^{-ax}}{1-e^{-bx}}\right)\right|_{\epsilon}^L \tag1\\\\
&=-\log\left(\frac ab\right) \tag 2
\end{align}$$

Note that in going from $(1)$ to $(2)$, we used the facts that $(i)$ $\lim_{L\to \infty} e^{-ax}=0$, $(ii)$ $\log (1)=0$, and $(iii)$

$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\left(\frac{1-e^{-a\epsilon}}{1-e^{-b\epsilon}}\right)=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\frac{ae^{-a\epsilon}}{be^{-b\epsilon}}=\frac{a}{b} \tag 3$$

where we used L'Hospital's Rule to arrive at $(3)$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't quite understand when you integrate it first time, is not there $e^{ax} -e^{bx} $ term too along with log ?

Comment: The derivative of $\log (1-e^{-ax})$ is $\frac{ae^{-ax}}{1-e^{-ax}}$

Comment: Oh yes that is right, I am sorry.
Could you please explain in a few words why the double limit is $-log(a/b)$ ? It does not seem so obvious to me.

Comment: Sure.  Give me a moment.

Comment: Thanks Sir. Just the very last bit, why is $1-e^{-a\epsilon} =ae^{-a\epsilon} ?$

Comment: L'hospital's Rule.  They are not equal.  The limits in $(3)$ are equal.

Comment: Oh God of course, it was the derivative simply... Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.